# SQL Server - Referencing another column in a CHECK clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

hope you're having a good day.
I want to do something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE Certificat
 (
 num_certificat SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 description TEXT NOT NULL,
 Date_depot DATE NOT NULL CHECK(Date_depot <= GETDATE()),
 Date_validation DATE NOT NULL CHECK(Date_validation > Date_depot),
 num_auteur SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 num_innovation SMALLINT NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT pk_numc PRIMARY KEY(num_certificat),
 CONSTRAINT fk_au FOREIGN KEY(num_auteur) REFERENCES Auteur(num_auteur) ON 
 DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_inn FOREIGN KEY(num_innovation) REFERENCES 
 Innovation(num_innovation) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 );
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 8141, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   Column CHECK constraint for column 'Date_validation' references another column, table 'Certificat'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

So how can I reference another column into a CHECK clause? I want the table to reject entries with the `Date_depot` greater than `Date_validation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create it at the table level - not inline next to a column.

```
 CREATE TABLE Certificat
(
    num_certificat SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    Date_depot DATE NOT NULL CHECK(Date_depot <= GETDATE()),
    Date_validation DATE NOT NULL,
    num_auteur SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    num_innovation SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CHECK(Date_validation > Date_depot), /*<----- Moved here*/
    CONSTRAINT pk_numc PRIMARY KEY(num_certificat),
    CONSTRAINT fk_au FOREIGN KEY(num_auteur) REFERENCES Auteur(num_auteur) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_inn FOREIGN KEY(num_innovation) REFERENCES Innovation(num_innovation) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

You should also consider giving it an explicit name. For example

```
CONSTRAINT ck_validation_after_depot CHECK(Date_validation > Date_depot)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. I wonder why is it some sort of variable scoop like we see on other programming languages? (C/C++...etc)?

Comment: It's just a restriction of the TSQL grammar that constraints declared inline next to columns can only reference that column.